# ajax call serialize and deserialize data

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, json, serialization

I have the following ajax call:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/LoadCount.aspx/GetCounts",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: "",
                async: false,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                  var myObj = JSON.parse(data.d);
                  alert(myObj.length);
                  for (var i = 0; i < myObj.length; i++) {
                    alert(myObj[0]);
                  }

                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                    alert(err.Message);
                }
            });
        });
```

I am getting **undefined** when I alert the **length**

Here's my Method in my LoadCount.aspx

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string ObtenerContador()
{
    List<MenuItem> menu =(List<MenuItem>)HttpContext.Current.Session["MenuItems"];

    Dictionary<string, int> dic = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    foreach (MenuItemAMostrar item in menu)
    { 
        dic.Add(item.ControlID,1);
    };

    return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(dic); //or any other suggested serialization method
}
```

this is what I am getting in the success function:

```
{"MenuCLESAAsignar":1,"MenuOCGestores":1,"MenuOcAAutorizar":1,"MenuOcAAutorizarBanco":1,"MenuOCGestoresObservadas":1,"MenuCLESActivos":1,"MenuParametros":1,"MenuCLESConAddendaAAprobarSup":1,"MenuPendienteAprobacion":1,"MenuConsultaCLES":1}
```

The question is, how do I **deserialize** that dictionary in my ajax success function?
Once deserialized, how do I **populate** it, obtaining the data?

thanks!

Comment: What does your `data` look like `onsuccess` on the ajax side? Could you post a sample?

Comment: Yes, i have just edited my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As somebody else mentioned, you just use `JSON.parse()` to parse the data.

From there it just creates an object, and you can access the data with `.`.

Like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/SJGLF/1/

```
var myData = JSON.parse(jsonData);
for(var i in myData)
{
    console.log(i + " = " + myData[i]);
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I don't have those values (MenuCLESAAsignar, MenuOCGestores, etc).. I need to get BOTH values

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  Did you follow the link I posted?

Comment: I need to show the values, whichever they are.. I don't know if I'll get "MenuCLESAAsignar" o something else..

Comment: Are you saying that you don't know what will be in the dictionary?

Comment: I've updated my answer to loop through the object getting the key/value pair.

Comment: If you know the keys in the dictionary `myData.MenuCLESAAsignar` will give you the value of 1.  If you don't know the keys that will be in the dictionary, you can loop through all the elements of the object and get them that way.  (as seen in my updated answer)

Comment: Please follow the link I posted.  To see the output, press F12 and view the console.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this?

```
success: function (data)
{               
    var myObj = JSON.parse(data.d);
},
```

Comment: yes! that helped. But how do I populate through the dictionary? (I have edited my question)